# Uploading files via network drive mapping

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, network-drive

I have already mapped a network drive and added my site as a trusted site on internet explore,but each time am trying to upload a file ,i get the error asking me to add my site as a trusted site.

Comment: Use IE to sign-in and keep the session open until you finish copying

Comment: @AkshayRandive still getting this error

Comment: in IE open the library with "Open in explorer" option from Ribbon and try and try uploading that should definitely work

Comment: @AkshayRandive not working i noticed if i try uploading via sharepoint designer i get access denied

Comment: @AkshayRandive i created a new site and yes now everything is uploading but the error prevails in the old site

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Delete and re-add the old site in trusted site in IE.
2. Re-map network drive to the site with the issue.

Comment: Already tried those,the error persist